# Java Ticket Price Calculator if statement

Tags: java

Okay, so I would really appreciate this community's advice. I recently received my first programming project and I'm way in over my head. I have zero experience  with programming, but I'm going to give as much information as I can.

The project is a basic ticket pricing program that runs in the command prompt using java. We have to introduce the program with the name of the creator, ask for number of adult tickets wanted ($10 a piece), the number of student tickets ($5 a piece), use a switch statement or if statement to allow the user to select a discount (free shipping, 10% off, or best option), and finally calculate the total depending on the users choices.

The problem is that I'm just stuck on this whole switch statement thing and calculating the total. I'll include the code I have so far and I would really appreciate any help you can give.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double adult; //number of adult tickets
    double student; //number of student/senior tickets
    int option;
    double aamount = 10.00;
    double samount = 5.00;
    double purchasePrice = adult * aamount + student * samount;
    double total;

    final double DISCOUNT = 0.1;
    final double SHIPPING = 5.00;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("******** WELCOME TO THE TICKET PRICE CALCULATOR ********");
    System.out.println("            created by Shane Slobecheski");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("               Press enter to continue");
    kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("How many adult tickets do you wish to purchase? (ages 18-64): ");
    adult = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("How many student/senior tickets do you wish to purchase? (ages 0-17 or 65+): ");
    student = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please make a selection from the menu options below for additional savings");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("  Savings Menu");
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    System.out.println("1. Free Shipping");
    System.out.println("2. 10.0% discount");
    System.out.println("3. Apply whichever discount will save me the most money");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
    option = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Purchase price $"+ purchasePrice);

    purchasePrice = adult * aamount + student * samount;

}
}//end program
```

Comment: Where's the switch statement at all? and what's with all those print statements?

Comment: I think an if statement would be better so I literally haven't even started that part. And on top of that I'm kind of lost on how I would start. As for all the print statements, I don't know a more efficient way yet. This is the first practice I've really had since the class started.

Comment: Oh, and I just compiled it again and received an error telling me that student and adult haven't been initialized, but how can I when the user is supposed to enter them?

Comment: @sslobecheski You might want to first go through a basic tutorial. E.g. your println statements can either be simplyfied by using a loop or using the `\n` to archive multiple line breaks. Additionally you should try out `switch / if`first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not forget their first initialize variables

```
double adult=0; 
double student=0; 
int option=0;
double total=0;
```

and the switch structure has the following syntax, where p is the variable to assess its serious case option

```
   switch(op)
    {
        case 1:operations; break;
        case 2: operations;break;
        default: System.out.println("option no valid");
    }
```